# Express param undefined even tho I enter value into url

Tags: node.js, express, parameters

I have this endpoint

```
app.get('/getSongsByRadio/:from/:to/:radioid', (res, req) => {
(async() => {
    try {
        let sql = `SELECT playback.songid, song.name AS songName, author.name AS authorName, radio.name AS radioName, playback.playbackdatetime 
        FROM playback 
        INNER JOIN song ON playback.songid = song.id 
        INNER JOIN author ON song.authorid = author.id 
        INNER JOIN radio ON playback.radioid = radio.id 
        WHERE playbackdatetime BETWEEN $1 AND $2 AND radio.id = $3;`

        let values = [req.params.from, req.params.to, req.params.radioid]
        const result = await (conn.query(sql, values))
        
        console.log(result.rows)
        res.send(result.rows)
    } catch (err) { 
        console.error(err)
        throw(err)
    }
})()
```

})
I am trying to access this endpoint like this

```
http://localhost:3000/getSongsByRadio/1597310460/1597310460/1
```

But even tho I enter all three params I get this error in the console:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'from' of undefined
at /Users/lukasmac/code/radiaNemecko/nemeckoRadia/index.js:65:38
at /Users/lukasmac/code/radiaNemecko/nemeckoRadia/index.js:73:7
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/lukasmac/code/radiaNemecko/nemeckoRadia/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at next (/Users/lukasmac/code/radiaNemecko/nemeckoRadia/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have mistakenly swapped `res, req`. It should be `(req, res)`

and also you should rewrite your method like this

```
app.get('/getSongsByRadio/:from/:to/:radioid', async (req, res) => {
  try {
        let sql = `SELECT playback.songid, song.name AS songName, author.name AS authorName, radio.name AS radioName, playback.playbackdatetime 
        FROM playback 
        INNER JOIN song ON playback.songid = song.id 
        INNER JOIN author ON song.authorid = author.id 
        INNER JOIN radio ON playback.radioid = radio.id 
        WHERE playbackdatetime BETWEEN $1 AND $2 AND radio.id = $3;`

        let values = [req.params.from, req.params.to, req.params.radioid]
        const result = await (conn.query(sql, values))
        
        console.log(result.rows)
        res.send(result.rows)
    } catch (err) { 
        console.error(err)
        throw(err)
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

So you are not writing it properly, you can just use async with your main function like so.

```
app.get('/getSongsByRadio/:from/:to/:radioid', async (res, req) => {
    try {
        let sql = `SELECT playback.songid, song.name AS songName, author.name AS authorName, radio.name AS radioName, playback.playbackdatetime 
        FROM playback 
        INNER JOIN song ON playback.songid = song.id 
        INNER JOIN author ON song.authorid = author.id 
        INNER JOIN radio ON playback.radioid = radio.id 
        WHERE playbackdatetime BETWEEN $1 AND $2 AND radio.id = $3;`

        let values = [req.params.from, req.params.to, req.params.radioid]
        const result = await (conn.query(sql, values))
        
        console.log(result.rows)
        res.send(result.rows)
    } catch (err) { 
        console.error(err)
        throw(err)
    }
})
```